# Exception handling continuing the excecution

Tags: java, exception-handling, exception

This code is for continuing the execution after an exception, and this is ugly:

```
    int step=0;

    do{
        try{  
                switch(step)
                {
                case 0:
                    step=1;
                    methodAAAAACanThrowException();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    step=2;
                    methodBBBBBCanThrowException();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    step=3;
                    methodCCCCCanThrowException();
                    break;
                    //....

                    //more and more

                    //....
                case 25:
                    step=26;
                    methodZZZZZCanThrowException();                        
                }                      
        }catch( Exception ex)
        {  

            Logger.getLogger(ABC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }while(step<26);
}
```

**but writing a single try-catch loop for every call, seems even uglier..**

Is there any other more elegant option for doing that? 
thanks

Comment: The fact that you want do this is a bad sign. Why do you want to do this? What kind of function is this? What kind of methods is it calling? Chances are a better way to design your solution exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this?

Define a one-method interface like so:

```
public interface TryAndLogFailure { void execute(); }
```

Then define a method which takes an object which implements the interface and does your exception handling for you:

```
public void tryAndLogFailure(TryAndLogFailure talf) {
  try {
    talf.execute();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    logger.log(...);
  }
}
```

Now your calls to the methods can be sequential:

```
tryAndLogFailure(new TryAndLogFailure{ public void execute() { methodAAAACanThrowException(); } });
tryAndLogFailure(new TryAndLogFailure{ public void execute() { methodBBBBCanThrowException(); } });
// etc...
tryAndLogFailure(new TryAndLogFailure{ public void execute() { methodZZZZCanThrowException(); } });
```

Admittedly, this could probably be worked a little more to make it prettier, but this is my first crack off the top of my head. If only Java had support for closures.

(Also - I should note that I agree with Winston. The reason why this code feels ugly is because the concept itself is ugly. Catching `Exception` is almost never a good idea and requires strong justification. Given more context, we may be able to help you redesign the code to avoid this sort of code smell.)

Comment: Hello @mike9322, +1 for the answer, catching Exception is not the central point about this issue, I have post a similar question in stackoverflow, I think this is a Java debt, as you mention perhaps closures, I don't know, but is very messy to "retry" or continue the call of consecutive methods when some of them throws an exception, here is a better description of the general issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700173/java-exception-handling-in-non-sequential-tasks-pattern-good-practice this is my first post here, just to read different opinions, thanks

Comment: This might be technically sound but it hurts my eyes and brain. Having to do this is just another reason why Java needs lambda. `tryandLogFailure(() => methodAAAACanThrowException());` would of been perfect.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have to be as complicated as the other answers. And there are valid reasons for logging and continuing execution of a method.

It appears you are using the execution of the steps to advance to the next step regardless of exceptions. So it seems better to use a for loop.

I'm not really liking the use of switch statements to execute methods in order, but I think fixing that might go beyond the original intent of this question. Too bad Java doesn't have native lambda.

```
// Execute all steps regardless of exceptions
void executeAllSteps() {
    for (int step = 0; step < 26; ++step) {
        try {
            executeStep(step);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
             // Collect the exception in a list or add it to 
             // a log file.
        }
    }
}

void executeStep (int step) throws Exception {
    switch(step) {
        case 0:
            methodAAAAACanThrowException();
            break;
        case 1:
            methodBBBBBCanThrowException();
            break;
        case 2:
            methodCCCCCanThrowException();
            break;
        case 25:
            methodZZZZZCanThrowException();   
            break;                     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of `do` and `switch` is pointless. It's doing the same thing as simply calling each method sequentially and nothing more.

Just put those calls inside a `try` block.

```
try {
    methodAAAAACanThrowException();
    methodBBBBBCanThrowException();

}catch(Exception e) {
    Logger.getLogger(ABC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Wrong, that won't work, if methodAAAAACanThrowException(); throw an Exception then methodBBBBBCanThrowException(); won't be executed

Comment: Uh, ok. I'll leave it here so everyone will know what not to do.